# Curl return xml as array

Tags: php, xml, curl, google-places-api

I have a curl procedure in php which returns xml or JSON from Google Places API.
I understand Google Places requires that request is returned in XML or JSON.
I wonder if curl can translate this into an array for me?
I would prefer greatly not to do it myself.

Comment: Not really, but what's wrong with `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($data, TRUE);
```